# Link to external URL from Modx Revolution Menu

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I'm attempting to link to another site from the main navigation on my Modx Revolution 2.2.13-pl site.

I tried to create a weblink resource, but it simply loads up a page with the URL in the content of the page, then redirects to the homepage as if you had hit a page that did not exist.

Can anyone chime in on how to properly create a weblink in Modx?

Thanks.

Update: I am using a fully qualified URL to an external website.

Weblink setup:

[image: Weblink set up]

HTML Output:

[image: HTML Output]

I tried to get a SS of what happens when you click the link, but it redirects too fast. It's basically my template with the resource title in H4, then the URL in the weblink field on the page as a link in the content area. Then it redirects to the homepage (which is our default 404 action)

Answer (score 1):

This is works as expected. Compare with what you got.

Page:
[image]

Wayfinder output:

[image]

Comment: Updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: Please show source code of page, not html in console.